ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the follow
I am installing an AI on my PC.
This error get after install python install.py.
Do you know what should I do?

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account
all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of
the following dependency conflicts. gradio 3.50.2 requires numpy~=1.0,
but you have numpy 2.0.0 which is incompatible.

I try but it not worked.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
